# Jquery created list does not have styling

Tags: jquery, css, json

I have a dynamically created list that is inserted into the html with regular Jquery. The information for the list is pulled from an external JSON file and inserted into the proper tags.

The styling I have works fine if the elements are hard coded, of course, but I do not understand why it will not style inserted html from the script file.

The styling still affects the headlines of each menu item that I am trying to make, but not the nested items inside of the menu items.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$.getJSON( "externalJson.json", function( data ) {
    postData(data);
});

function postData(data){

    var html = "<ul>";

    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        //console.log(key + " " + value);

        if(typeof value == "object"){

        html += "<li><h3><span>" + key + "</span></h3><ul>";

            $.each(value.innerItem, function(i, j){
                console.log(i + " " + j.link);

                    html += "<li><a href=" + JSON.stringify(j.link) + ">" + j.item + "</a></li></ul>";

            });

            html += "</li>";
            html += "</ul>";


        } else {
            $('#content').append(key + " : " + value);
        }

    });

    $('#accordian').append(html);


};


$("#accordian h3").click(function(){

    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();

    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){
        $(this).next().slideDown();

    }
});
```

and here is my json :

```
{

"colors":"green",


"ItemTwo":
    {
      "innerItem":
            [{
                "item":"Keep Me! Don't Erase",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            },
            {
                "item":"kitten",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            },
            {
                "item":"kitten2",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            },
            {
                "item":"kitten3",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            }]
    },

"ItemThree":
    {
     "innerItem":
            [{
                "item":"meow",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            },
             {
                "item":"meow",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            },
            {
                "item":"meow",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            }]
    }
  }
```

Here is a JSFiddle with my styling and the result of what I'm trying to achieve. Unfortunately, the json variable doesn't quite work or show the added menu items.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cherrybomb95/8c0w2g4q/1/

Here is also a link to what my code currently produces with the external json file. Just click the folder link to "WhatsOnTheMenu" and you'll see it.

https://workspace-cherrysymphony.c9.io/

Let me know if you have any questions or issues with viewing my code.
Thank you.

Comment: You're generating invalid HTML, which is why it doesn't work

Comment: This is what you get -> http://jsfiddle.net/1c2e4fsp/

Comment: Thank you for the edited fiddle. It helps a bunch to see that. Do you know any way I could edit my code so that it does not produce that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the `<ul>` on each item in the inner `$.each` loop and the href attribute is not surrounded by quotes. The correct code is as follows:

```
function postData(data) {
    var html = "<ul>";
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if(typeof value == "object") {
            html += "<li><h3><span>" + key + "</span></h3><ul>";
            $.each(value.innerItem, function(i, j){
                html += "<li><a href=\"" + JSON.stringify(j.link) + "\">" + j.item + "</a></li>";
            });
            html += "</ul></li>";
        } else {
            $('#content').append(key + " : " + value);
        }
    });
    html += "</ul>";
    $('#accordian').append(html);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "externalJson.json", function( data ) {
        postData(data);
    });

    $("#accordian").on("click", "h3", function(){
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) $(this).next().slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: I added the escape characters, but I still get the same result as before except with actual links now. Where should I put my tags so that they function properly?

Comment: Well the markup looks correct with the repeated `</ul>` removed. Did you also remove this tag? It's on the line which adds the list item containing the link.

Comment: Sorry just realised a mistake - it's not that it needed to be removed, rather that it had to be moved to the line after the `$.each` loop. I have corrected the code above.

Comment: I removed the tag, and now the list items that appeared under the menu items disappeared, but they do know slide out when the menu item is clicked on.

Comment: Did you add the `</ul>` to the line after? If so, and it still doesn't work, can you create a JS Fiddle which outputs the exact same results you are getting?

Comment: I put in your changes, but the result is back to the way it was before now.

Comment: Sounds odd. I'm gonna try to create a JS Fiddle with hardcoded JSON.

Comment: I did add it to the line after, and that is what caused it to go back to the way before. You should be able to see my result in the second link of my question, but I cannot figure out how to get my JSFiddle to work with the json object. I'm trying to get it working though.

Comment: Best bet is to use dev tools to get the exact JSON fed back by the external source, and then call `postData(content-of-file)`. I'll have a look at your link.

Comment: Got it! http://jsfiddle.net/ClarkeyBoy1987/fhdrzz4c/1/. The issue wasn't just the inner `$.each` loop closing the `<ul>` on every item, but the outer `$.each` loop also closing the outer `<ul>` on every item. Moving both `</ul>`s outside the respective loop resolved it.

Comment: Oh, you are the best!! I've been fighting with this for a day now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem! I'll fix my answer in a moment. I often face similar issues at work where I struggle with something for hours or even a day - often coming back to it the next day, with a fresh mind, or talking through it with a colleague helps a lot.

Comment: I do have another small problem really quick though. The answer works when you hardcode the data, but it's not working when the data is external. You wouldn't happen to know why that is, would you?

Comment: hmmm all I did was copy the contents of the file. I'll have a look at the fiddle and see if anything springs to mind.

Comment: Right just updated my answer again - notice that I've only wrapped the JSON and accordian calls in `$(document).ready(function() {...});` and the function definition of `postData` is outside of this. Give this a try and let me know the result.

Comment: I moved things around, but it still does not allow me to click the menu items and see the submenus.

Comment: Alright just figured it out - the JSON request doesn't finish loading until after the accordian stuff has executed. i.e. it initiates the JSON request, executes the accordian code and then finishes the JSON request. See my answer for the fix - should just be a case of changing it to `$("#accordian").on("click", "h3", fn);` :)